# Defining global variable in main()

Tags: c++, global-variables

I want to define global array (used in other functions) based on input from **main();** (concretely array size). The *extern* keyword didn't help.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

void gen_sieve_primes(void);

int main() {
    int MaxNum;
    cin >> MaxNum;
    int *primes = new int[MaxNum];
    delete[] primes;
    return 0;
}
//functions where variable MaxNum is used
```

Comment: 1) Don't use globals.  2) Don't use arrays; use containers like `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you want an array and not a `std::vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare it outside of main:

```
int maxNum;
int main() {
...
}
```

Ideally, you don't do this at all. Globals are rarely useful, and hardly ever (or rather: never) needed.

Comment: Sorry. Larson and Persson got me answer. But it's my failure that you didn't understand my code(I had extern before int MaxNum, what I didn't want)

Comment: @Dundee By the way, is there any reason at all you're not just passing that array (or better, vector) as a parameter instead of making it global?

Comment: I'm newbie in C++, so I don't do so big projects - so global variables aren't problem for me. But I know that better is NOT use global variables. I need that array in 2 other functions, so I need make it global. Or have you better solution how to do it?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, pass the array with parameters. This has nothing to do with size of the project really, globals get you into trouble very quickly. Global variables that is, constants occasionally have their place.

Answer (score 5):

Just define it in global scope

```
int MaxNum;
int main(){
    cin >> MaxNum;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is defining a variable in global scope, not `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the array outside of the main function's brackets.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void gen_sieve_primes(void);

(Declare the variables here!)

int main() {
     extern int MaxNum;
     cin >> MaxNum;
     int *primes = new int[MaxNum];
     delete[] primes;
     return 0;
}
//functions where variable MaxNum is used
```